# current culture of request in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

How can I acquire the `CultureInfo` of a request in a View?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` will return the culture for the thread currently processing the request. This is also accessible through `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentCulture`.  Are you having a specific issue?

Comment: Well, that works for the current thread, not the request, right? What I want is to set the culture specific to the browser to a jquery calendar.

Comment: The request is executed on a thread, so the context you are accessing the `CultureInfo` in, is the current request.

Answer (score 17):

you can get CultureInfo by System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture