# Show Weight and Volume based on Culture logged in

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a requirement , where I have to show Weight and Volume in KG and cubic meter(or pounds and cubic feet) based on the user logged in culture.

So suppose in the country where Kg and cubic meter is followed, I want to display weight and volume in those, where as the country where pounds and cubic feet are used , I want to display weight and volume in those.

I am using MVC3 to develop my application.So as per requirement the View should show Weight and Volume in KG and cubic meter or pounds and cubic feet respectively.

It will be good if any one can share a code sample to do the same.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since only three countries don't use metric, detect their code and set a property in your view model IsMetric based on this and display accordingly ( or set the actual string name Kg or Lbs for ex to use in your view model from the controller)

The lone three countries
http://m.ca.gizmodo.com/5786004/these-are-the-three-countries-who-dont-use-the-metric-system

to read the culture 
[current culture of request in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724429/current-culture-of-request-in-a-view)

Comment: Thanks Adam!! As I am having multiple views , so is there a way to set this across all the views.I mean instead of doing this in each view

Comment: Just define a helper method to get them or anywhere you use them, have a class named UnitNames and define a DisplayFor template that in turn does the lookups for this class, or simply use a shared viewmodel  called UnitNamesViewModel that contains the properties which in turn have the logic in them to return the proper names as I described above. I think I like that last option the best. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes Adam.I have gone with the second option